# TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null in React

Tags: reactjs

Trying to clean input through setting `value` of input to `''` and getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './add-item.sass'

export default class AddItem extends Component {
  state: {
    label: ''
  }

  onLabelChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      label: event.target.value
    })
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.onItemAdded(this.state.label)
    this.setState({
      label: ''
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="add-item d-flex"
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text"
          className="form-control add-item__input"
          onChange={this.onLabelChange}
          placeholder="new 2do"
          value={this.state.label}
        />
        <button
          className="btn btn-success"
          type="submit"
        >Add</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error referring to ?

Comment: ```value={this.state.label}``` inside the <input> tag

Comment: `constructor () { super(); this.state = { label: '' } }`

Comment: Thanks, @HosseinZare, it helps
Can U provide some articles or information Why this happen ?

Comment: Because it should be `state = { label: '' }` (`=` instead of `:`).

Comment: @JJJ as in my example

Comment: Uh, no. Like I said, you have `state: ` when it should be `state = `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace this:

```
state: { // By the way this needs to be  state=  not  state:
  label: ''
}
```

with

```
constructor () {
  super();

  this.state = {
    label: ''
  }
}
```

**Note: Defining initial states outside of the constructor is a bad example.**

Answer (score -1):

You can also go without a constructor. Just add "this" before the state:

```
this.state: {
  label: ''
}
```